# Are There Metrics For Cohesion And Coupling?

Tags: code-metrics

Is there a metric analogous to the [McCabe Complexity measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) to measure how cohesive a routine is and also how loosely (or tightly) coupled the routine is to other code in the same code base?

Comment: related: [How do you balance out code structuring (few big functions vs. many small ones)?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/201130/31260)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the metric you are looking for is LCOM4, although it applies more to classes.

Sonar explains it nicely [here](http://www.sonarsource.org/clean-up-design-at-class-level-with-sonar/):

> ...metric : LCOM4 (Lack Of Cohesion Methods) to measure how cohesive classes are. Interpreting this metric is pretty simple as value 1 means that a class has only one responsibility (good) and value X means that a class has probably X responsibilities (bad) and should be refactored/split.
>
> There is not any magic here, only common sense. Let’s take a simple example with class Driver. This class has two fields : Car and Brain, and five methods : drive(), goTo(), stop(), getAngry() and drinkCoffee(). Here is the dependency graph between those components. There are three blocks of related components, so LCOM4 = 3, so the class seems to have three different responsibilities and breaks the Single Responsibility Principle.
>   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2527G.png]
>
> ...

It's a great tool, if you can use it. :)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci No problem. :)

Comment: Just too bad they don't go into how they calculate the metric.

Comment: This might help with that: http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-cohesion.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you refactor that diagram to obey the Single Responsibility Principle? `brain.setAngry(driver)`? `car.applyBreaks(driver)`?

Comment: I doubt that code-based cohesion metrics can truly be indicative of interface level cohesion, and may even promote bad programming: http://mortoray.com/2015/04/29/cohesion-and-coupling-good-measures-of-quality/#comment-20266

Comment: This is conflating `internal` cohesion that should be exhibited within the structure of a class vs `external` cohesion that should be exhibited by closely collaborating components (in particular by those residing within a module or layer or that mediate the boundaries between modules and layers.) For the later, I would suggest to rely on connascence and and instability/coupling metrics.

Comment: Given link to sonar is broken

Answer (score 17):

- Afferent coupling: Number of responsibilities
- Efferent coupling: Number of dependencies
- Instability: Ratio of efferent coupling to total coupling (Afferent + Efferent).

Instability is supported in various code metric tools.

Comment: Thanks @Brian--exactly the sort of thing I was hoping to find.